# Create Multiple Columns from an XSL value-of Select "."

Tags: xml, xslt

This is the XML Table

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="CD-Catalog-New.xsl"?>
<catalog>
  <cd>
    <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
    <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
    <country>USA</country>
    <company>Columbia</company>
    <price>10.90</price>
    <years>
      <year>1985</year>
      <year>1986</year>
      <year>1987</year>
    </years>
   </cd>
  <cd>
    <title>Hide your heart</title>
    <artist>Bonnie Tyler</artist>
    <country>UK</country>
    <company>CBS Records</company>
    <price>9.90</price>
    <years>
      <year>1988</year>
      <year>1988</year>
    </years>
  </cd>
```

This is the XSL Code currently using

```
  <xsl:for-each select="years">
    <td><xsl:value-of select="."/></td>
  </xsl:for-each>
```

Resulting Columns
[Resulting Columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fJGeJ.jpg)

```
 Columns
 Year1            Year2     Year3
 1985 1986 1987 
 1988 1988
```

Would Like

```
 Columns
 Year1     Year2     Year3
 1985      1986      1987 
 1988      1988
```

Should be easy but did not find this example anywhere.
Just Starting to learn XSL

Comment: Got it to work with your help, Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is only one `years` element per `cd` in your XML, so doing `<xsl:for-each select="years">` will select just that single element.

When you do `xsl:value-of` on an element with multiple descendants, it will concatenate together the text value of all those descendants, which is why you get all years showing together in a single cell.

You should do this to select the child `year` elements individually.

```
<xsl:for-each select="years/year">
```

Comment: It worked perfectly, I think I now understand the Concept. Thank You very much.